# An array of arrays confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to display the levels I'll have using this code...

```
levelArray[0] = ["player", "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty",
    "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty","empty",
    "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "wall",
    "wall", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty",
    "box", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty",
    "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "wall", "empty",
    "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "ghost", "wall","ghost"];

for(var i = 0; i < edge; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < edge; j++)
    {
        switch(levelArray[i])
        {
            case "empty":   // empty location
                ctx.drawImage(emptyTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "wall":    // wall block
                ctx.drawImage(wallTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "box":     // box block
                ctx.drawImage(boxTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "ghost":   // enemy sprite
                ctx.drawImage(ghostTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "player":  // player sprite
                ctx.drawImage(playerTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
        }
        currentX += elementEdge;
    }
    currentY += elementEdge;
}
```

however I receive an error on the switch line "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" and I don't really understand it.

Edit:
edge is defined previously like this

```
edge = Math.sqrt(levelArray.length)
```

Comment: is `edge` defined somewhere?

Comment: Where's edge defined? And you're using it for both for loops? Shouldn't it be levelArray.length and levelArray[i].length?

Comment: levelArray[i] will never be equal to a string.

Comment: updated with edge definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the inner loop. I believe you want this instead:

```
switch(levelArray[i][j])
```

---

In [your source code](http://jsfiddle.net/teEWK/5/), that snippet is inside a `setupCanvas` function, with takes `levelArray` as an argument. Since you're not passing anything when you call `setupCanvas`, it's considered `undefined`. Hence the errors you're getting.

Comment: Make sure edge is defined, and levelArray is properly initialized (var levelArray = []) somewhere

Comment: Edge is defined and levelArray is properly initialised

Comment: @Cody Could you setup a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Cody That's too much code for me to debug right now. But I ran it, and didn't get any errors.

Comment: Click on the output, I just threw it all in so it'd be a proper representation of what I have

Comment: I don't understand how it's undefined. I declare, initialise and populate the array at the very top of the script

Comment: @Cody You're not *passing* it to the function, but you declared the function as `function setupCanvas(levelArray)`. Remove the parameter from the function definition to access the array from the parent scope, or actually pass it when you call your function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access your array of levelArray like this:

> switch(levelArray[0][i])

, because this levelArray[i] will return array in case i=0 for sure and other cases of i if you have placed more arrays!

Comment: What is the value of edge? Try instead of edge, 48 and remove one of the two for loops.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, `levelArray` isn't declared or initialized, so it doesn't have a type. A simple `var levelArray = [];` at the top should fix your problem.

UPDATE:

After trying your code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teEWK/), it also looks like you're not looping through the second-level array. So you'll also need to change `levelArray[i][j]`.

After that, I get an error that `edge` is not defined. So you have some work there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do something like this:

Instead of a multidimensional array (which you didn't really do), I use a regular array, and every `edge` steps, i reset the currentX parameter and increases the currentY parameter

```
var edge = 7, elementEdge=20;
var levelArray = ["player", "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty",
    "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty","empty",
    "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "wall",
    "wall", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty",
    "box", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty",
    "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "wall", "empty",
    "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "ghost", "wall","ghost"];

var currentX = 0, currentY = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < levelArray.length; i++) {
  switch (levelArray[i]) {
    // All your cases here...
  }
  currentX += elementEdge;
  if (i % edge == 0) {
    currentX = 0;
    currentY += elementEdge;
  }
}
```

Another answer could be to really use a multidimensional array:

```
var levelArray = [["player", "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty"],
    ["empty", "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty","empty"],
    ["empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "wall"],
    ["wall", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty"],
    ["box", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty"],
    ["empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "wall", "empty"],
    ["wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "ghost", "wall","ghost"]];

for(var i = 0; i < levelArray.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < levelArray[i].length; j++)
    {
        switch(levelArray[i][j])
        {
            case "empty":   // empty location
                ctx.drawImage(emptyTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "wall":    // wall block
                ctx.drawImage(wallTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "box":     // box block
                ctx.drawImage(boxTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "ghost":   // enemy sprite
                ctx.drawImage(ghostTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "player":  // player sprite
                ctx.drawImage(playerTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
        }
        currentX += elementEdge;
    }
    currentY += elementEdge;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a multi-level array (bidimensional)

```
levelArray = [
    ["player", "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty"],
    ["empty", "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty","empty"],
    ["empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "wall"],
    ["wall", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty"],
    ["box", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty"],
    ["empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "wall", "empty"],
    ["wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "ghost", "wall","ghost"]
];
```

Now you can iterate with it like this

```
var elemWidth = 20, elemHeight = 20;
for (var i=0; i<levelArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<levelArray[i].length; j++) {
        switch(levelArray[i][j]) {
            case "empty": ctx.drawImage(emptyTile, i*elemWidth, j*elemHeight); break;
            case "wall": ctx.drawImage(wallTile, i*elemWidth, j*elemHeight); break;
            case "box": ctx.drawImage(boxTile, i*elemWidth, j*elemHeight); break;
            case "ghost": ctx.drawImage(ghostTile, i*elemWidth, j*elemHeight); break;
            case "player": ctx.drawImage(playerTile, i*elemWidth, j*elemHeight); break;
        }
    }
}
```